# A forall that is invariant but can not be proved

Tags: dafny

In this code

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/DmBh

assert forall x:: x in multisetOfTree(t.right) ==> t.root <= x;

is not proved at line 36, however it is part of the invariant.
Indeed, you can uncomment the invariant in line 31 and comment the line 36 and
it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are missing parentheses in the definition of `isABB`.

It should read:

```
predicate isABB (t:Tree<int>)
{
match t
    case Empty => true
    case Node(l,d,r) => isABB(l) && isABB(r) 
                        && (forall x :: x in multisetOfTree(l) ==> x <= t.root)
                        && (forall x :: x in multisetOfTree(r) ==> t.root <= x)
}
```